# How to concat $ in a MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I want to prefix a string with $ using $concat (it's a price). Obviously I cannot do

```
$concat: ["$", "$price"]
```

because `$` is the valueof operator. I tried `\$`, but that resolves to `$` and throws the same error. Tried `\\$` but that printed `\$`

So what's the way to do this? Is it even supported?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
$concat: [ {$literal: "$"}, {$toString: "$price"} ]
```